# ¿Como cambiar img src dependiendo la extensión de un archivo en PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando cambiar una imagen dependiendo de la extensión del archivo que haya. He intentado varias maneras pero ninguna es la que busco.

Me gustaría que saliese esa imagen solo en archivos `.pdf`. A ver si vosotros me sabéis decir cómo puedo hacerlo.

Esto es lo que tengo.

```
if(count($files) > 0 ){
  foreach($files as $file) { ?>
   <div class="mt-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card bg-transparent border-secondary m-auto" id="pdf">
            <?php if (finfo_file('.pdf')) echo '<img class="card-img-top" id="imgpdf" src="assest/images/pdflogo.png">' ?>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center"><?php echo basename($file, '.pdf')."\n"; ?></h5><a class="btn btn-primary " href=<?php echo $file; ?>>Descargar</a>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } 
} else {
  echo 'No files';
}
```

Edito por aquí: os pongo el valor de `$files` y alguna cosilla más:

```html
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path);
 
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile() && in_array($fileinfo->getExtension(),array('pdf','pptx'))) { 
      array_push($allfiles,$path.$fileinfo->getBasename());
    }
  }
  
  
  $files = array_slice( $allfiles, $start, $limit ) //el &start y &limit es que lo tengo paginado
```

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos un ejemplo del valor de `$file`?

Comment: Ahí lo tienes ya editado.. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener la extensión del archivo en la variable `$file` y poder controlar si es igual a `PDF`, podrías utilizar [`pathinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php), por ejemplo, así:

```
<?php
$extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$logo = '';
if ($extension == 'pdf') {
    $logo = 'pdflogo.png';
}

if ($logo) {
    echo '<img class="card-img-top imgpdf" src="assest/images/'.$logo.'">';
}
```